# sql list games and total reviews with left join?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join, inner-join

I am displaying the list of games and using left join table review.
I need to just take the total reviews of each game to have an output:

```
array (
[0] => array ('title' => 'game1', 'reviews' => 0), 
[1] => array ('title' => 'game2', 'reviews' => 2), 
[2] => array ('title' => 'game3', 'reviews' => 0), 
)
```

I'm having trouble mounting the sql

my sql

```
select A.title, review.text from game as A
left join game_review as review on review.id_game = A.id
limit 5
```

my db

```
tbl-games [id, title]
game1
game2
game3

tbl-review [id, id_game, text]
review of game2
review of game2
```

Comment: Can you take a snapshot of your table or post a table structure?

Comment: Why are you limiting your query by 5 ?

Comment: damn it I have the right to display as you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do the Job i think

```
select game.title, count(game_review.text) from game_review, game where game.id = game_review.id
```

or

```
select game.title, count(review.text) from game 
left join game_review on game.id = game_review.id_game
```

Comment: so i posted a second solution (check and correct tablenames yourself)

Comment: I reduced the second example-code to the minimum, but ist still the same logic. Did you test it with phpmyadnim?